# Chrome DevTools lists the same directory three times

Tags: javascript, debugging, typescript, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

The Chrome DevTools Sources tab shows our app's `src` directory in three different ways. Why does Chrome do this? How can we make Chrome list the `src` directory once instead of three times?

[image]